# Python object output to PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, object

After reading related questions, I have to mention my question here.

I'm running a python script to fetch the data from Google place API. Somehow managing with PHP, I converted list of objects into below output:

```
[   {
    'fri_hours': "b'9:00 AM \\xe2\\x80\\x93 8:00 PM'",
    'wed_hours': "b'9:00 AM \\xe2\\x80\\x93 8:00 PM'",
    'sun_hours': "b'Closed'",
    'photo_reference': '',
    'phone_number': b'+1 212-354-1006',
    'state': b'New York',
    'country': b'United States',
    'place_id': 'ChIJ8cFYDKpZwokRpC04mEYm20s',
    'thu_hours': "b'9:00 AM \\xe2\\x80\\x93 8:00 PM'",
    'business_name': b'CarLeo Hair Salon',
    'address': b'22West 38th Street',
    'city': b'New York',
    'mon_hours': "b'9:00 AM \\xe2\\x80\\x93 6:00 PM'",
    'type': 'beauty salon',
    'sat_hours': "b'Closed'",
    'tue_hours': "b'9:00 AM \\xe2\\x80\\x93 8:00 PM'",
    'postal_code': '10018',
    'website': 'http://www.carleohairsalon.com/',
    'rating': 4.6   } ][   {
    'fri_hours': "b'8:00 AM \\xe2\\x80\\x93 8:00 PM'",
    'wed_hours': "b'8:00 AM \\xe2\\x80\\x93 8:00 PM'",
    'sun_hours': "b'Closed'",
    'photo_reference': 'CmRaAAAAe8XIMwcPu3uhohYjJ-dQt69rtZ-x2XJ-I28USF-LphSaVH4Gt-_JUmB06TGnOKKmAqSjnhGuFqUKb7pitV1twViGVE7znVYLSdRYZ72LKjtlXT47YapfEreCmd9lK1R8EhCEJ2Pb2Fpe2sbfbOF3hXgmGhRaJbdZKiF8S0GxdzVj3r7mQphVtw',
    'phone_number': b'+1 212-688-6498',
    'state': b'New York',
    'country': b'United States',
    'place_id': 'ChIJ0SFDYuVYwokRXJvyfmR9kec',
    'thu_hours': "b'8:00 AM \\xe2\\x80\\x93 8:00 PM'",
    'business_name': b'Mizu Salon',
    'address': b'505Park Avenue',
    'city': b'New York',
    'mon_hours': "b'10:00 AM \\xe2\\x80\\x93 6:00 PM'",
    'type': 'beauty salon',
    'sat_hours': "b'9:00 AM \\xe2\\x80\\x93 7:00 PM'",
    'tue_hours': "b'8:00 AM \\xe2\\x80\\x93 7:00 PM'",
    'postal_code': '10022',
    'website': 'http://www.mizuforhair.com/',
    'rating': 4.4   } ]
```

Now, simply I want to convert above output into a single array containing sub-arrays of the object using PHP

I have tried with using foreach loop but getting the same output.

Comment: Did you try converting your list to json? In php you can than `json_decode` the contents and you should have your array

Comment: Already tried but getting list of single objects so doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your python script do something like

```
import json
#some code here
jsonStr = json.dumps(myListFromGooglePlaces)
#whatever you do to get it to php
```

and then as mentioned in my comment above

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: Tried this and getting error that json is not serializable

Comment: What python version are your using?

Comment: Hello Domenik, I'm using Python 3.5.2

Comment: Can you print your list before encoding (what you get back from your API call) and post it here?

Comment: If you are really having a list, that code will work. So also print the type of your variable

Answer (score 0):

You could use json_decode function

```
j_obj = '[{ ....}]';

$array = json_decode($j_obj,true);
```

Comment: I'm getting each object in single array and that's also one of the issue